# Symbol color in postscript terminal

Tags: gnuplot, postscript

I've a top view of a pm3d plot in black and white. I am rendering the plot via postscript terminal enhanced eps.

I've to place zeta symbol over the data in white color. I've used

```
set label "{/Symbol=11 \245} = 1.0" at first 0.25, first 0.75 tc rgbcolor "#FFFFFF"
```

command. But the symbol is being rendered in black color. My terminal command is

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color font "Helvectica, 9" size 6.5cm, 6cm.
```

I've removed the tag color, and yet the color is still black.

What could be the command for a white symbol? I'm using gnuplot version 5.2.

My *.eps output:

```
/Helvetica findfont 90 scalefont setfont
1.000 UL
LTb
LCb setrgbcolor
1105 1598 M
63 0 V
1.000 UP
stroke
LCb setrgbcolor
644 1547 M
[ [(Symbol) 110.0 0.0 true true 0 (z)]
[(Helvetica) 90.0 0.0 true true 0 ( = 1.0)]
] -36.7 MLshow
```

I've attached below the image of the output, where I've shown what label appears as (I've moved it to x position 0.5). [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your command works correctly when run here, or at any rate it prints a label in white.  Note, however

- The symbol \245 renders as ∞ rather than ζ.  I think you want `\172`.
- The font name `Helvetica` is misspelled.
- To make sure the label is not hidden by the pm3d surface you should add the "front" attribute.

I split the command into three lines for clarity

```
set label 1 "{/Symbol=11 \172} = 1.0" at first 0.25, first 0.75
set label 1 tc rgbcolor "#FFFFFF"
set label 1 front
```

The corresponding code in the *.eps output looks like this:

```
1.00 1.00 1.00 C
1144 2527 M
[ /Symbol reencodeISO15 def
[(Symbol) 110.0 0.0 true true 0 (z)]
[(Helvetica) 90.0 0.0 true true 0 ( = 1.0)]
] -36.7 MLshow
```

The first line sets the color to white.
The second line moves to the position on the page.
The following four lines print the label.

Does your output produce a different sequence of PostScript commands? Showing the relevant fragment of the output might help debug the problem.

**EDIT**

The equivalent section of *.eps output if the terminal is `set term postscript eps mono` rather than `set term postscript eps color`:

```
LCb setrgbcolor
1144 2527 M
[ /Symbol reencodeISO def
[(Symbol) 110.0 0.0 true true 0 (z)]
[(Helvetica) 90.0 0.0 true true 0 ( = 1.0)]
] -36.7 MLshow
```

Comment: You're right about the symbol code. I was just wondering if it was at all rendering zeta, so I had changed the symbol code. I've added tag 'front'. But the color is still black.

Comment: I can reproduce your *.eps output if and only if I say `set term postscript eps mono` rather than `set term postscript eps color`.  Are you certain that your script is selecting color output?